# What is the difference between “advise” and “advice”

Tags: difference, word-difference

What is the difference between “advise” and “advice”

Comment: (1) "Advise" is pronounced with /z/, "advice" with /s/. (2) In BrE, the same verb("s")/noun("c") distinction exists between the pairs "license"/"licence", "practise"/"practice", "prophesy"/"prophecy", but without any distinction of pronunciation. (3) In AmE "license" is usual for both noun and verb, and "practice" for both noun and verb (with "practise" an accepted variant of both). AmE usually uses "prophesy" verb and "prophecy" noun, though with "prophesy" as an accepted variant.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two words is actually pretty straightforward. **advise** is a verb which means to provide someone with advice and **advice** is a noun (and an uncountable one at that—those are the ones that don't take indefinite articles) which means a piece of information that's considered useful or valuable in a given context.

A couple of examples:

> I would **advise** you not to smoke around here. This is a gas station after all! Do you want to blow us all up?
>
> Could you please give some **advice** on how to take care of your cats?